# Alternate to React hook Form useWatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

For my React app, I am consuming React Hook Form (which is on on older version v5 which does not have useWatch)

So, I am currently using watch() to watch my input fields and update my global state on every key input.

Since I do not have an option to upgrade my underlying React Hook Form version, is there any alternate way to optimize the use of watch() for input field entry ?

UPDATED

```
const inputField = watch(field.id);

const updateGlobalState = _.debounce(() => {
    handleInputChange(field.id, inputField); // This updates the global state (context api obj) in parent component and I update my "defaultValues" passed to the form with the updated value
}, 300);

useMemo(() => {
    setValue(field.id, props?.defaultValues?.[field.id]); // I need this, since there can be use cases where updates in some other field say dropdown causes me to empty out this text field id.
}, [props?.defaultValues]);

useMemo(() => {
        updateGlobalState();    
}, [inputField]);
```

Two important points from above;

1. Call to handleInputChange updates my global state (`{field1: 'A', field2: 'B'}`) and I update my "defaultValues" passed to the form with the updated value
2. I use setValue, since there can be use cases where updates in some other field say a dropdown causes me to empty out this text field id.

Comment: `update my global state on every key input.` What global state are you updating? Why does it need to be updated on keystroke?

Comment: So one reason is there are multiple dynamic sections with fields and there can be dependent fields...Other reason is on submit of the form, I actually take the values from the global state for the submit payload.

Comment: Thanks for the response! While may question may seem beside the point, one of the bigger problems I've dealth with in react over the years is uncomplicating the problems that happen when people try to synchronize form state (which is usually ephemeral) with global (more) persitent state. Because of hook form's very useful built in utilities, even in v5, I'd argue to keep form state local (e.g. within the form) as much as possible for as long as possible. But, this depends entirely on your app. If you're not experiencing problems duplicating the form state into global state, then keep it going.

Comment: Yeah, because of the dependent fields is where I need to duplicate the form state into global state....For now, the only thing I am now trying to solve now is (if you look at the UPDATED code in my original question), I want to remove the setValue and still being able to handle the use case where updates in some other field say a dropdown causes me to empty out this text field id. I am unable to get this use case working without the usage of setValue explicitly. I was wondering if it is somehow possible to get this working with some other way...may be watch...Not sure?

Comment: I am not entirely clear how watch works when the 2nd argument i.e. defaultValue  is passed...specifically in terms of how it then works with the useEffect...i.e. when no 2nd argument is provided and when 2nd argument is provided....

Comment: You have to use setValue to update the value of a field in response to some other field.

Comment: Ok...so updaring defaultValues has no impact in updating the field in the DOM...after the initial load ?

Comment: No, it does not. You have to use setValue or reset

Comment: Oh k...I was looking at the documentation and found one feature called "values"...Not sure if I can leverage that to update the DOM value https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254146/discussion-between-adam-jenkins-and-copenndthagen).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a few ways to optimize the use of `watch()` in React Hook Form v5.

1. **Debounce the input**: Debouncing is a technique where you delay processing the input until the user has stopped typing for a certain amount of time. This can be done using lodash's `debounce` function or a similar implementation. This way, you're not updating the global state on every keystroke, but rather after the user has stopped typing for a certain amount of time.
2. **Use `getValues(field)` instead of `watch(field)` where possible**: If you only need the value of a field at a specific point in time (like when the form is submitted), you can use `getValues(field)` instead of `watch(field)`. `getValues(field)` doesn't cause a re-render when the field changes, so it's more efficient if you don't need to keep track of the field's value in real-time.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import _ from 'lodash';

function MyForm() {
  const { register, watch, getValues } = useForm();
  const firstName = watch('firstName');
  const lastName = watch('lastName');

  // Debounce the function that updates the global state
  const updateGlobalState = _.debounce((firstName, lastName) => {
    // Update the global state here
  }, 300);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Only update the global state if both fields are filled out
    if (firstName && lastName) {
      updateGlobalState(firstName, lastName);
    }
  }, [firstName, lastName]);

  return (
    <form>
      <input name="firstName" ref={register} />
      <input name="lastName" ref={register} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: One is I loved your getValues suggestion....but in my case, since there are multiple dynamic sections with fields which can be potentially dependent on each other, I maintain and update the field values in a global state and also use this global state on submit...so looks like I would have to rule out getValues in my case

Comment: I also tried the debounce option and added my code in the origin question under UPDATED....so it is in a generic Field component which gets instantiated for all my dynamic fields....and because I am using setValue, updating global state via the call to handleInputChange, it is not working as expected....it would be really helpful if you have a look at my code to get some understanding about my setup and see if there are any additional inputs from your end.